Hot plate on Shabbos for Chazarah. Cover or no?
Based on my observations, there seems to be a general understanding that when people use a hot plate or platah for Chazarah on Shabbos, they place the pot directly onto the hotplate. However, when it comes to placing cold items on the hotplate, they tend to add an additional thicker layer instead of placing them directly on it. My question is: why is this the case?
To elaborate, Chazal instructed us to perform Garuf Ukatum with fires prior to Shabbos to allow for Shehiya or Chazarah. The reasoning behind this is either related to the concern of Mechzei Kmevashel (it appears as though one is cooking) or the potential to stoke the fire. With a hotplate, while we are less concerned about stoking the fire, we still have concerns regarding Mechzei Kmevashel. (some do cook on hotplates regularly, and since the hotplate has the capability to cook, we treat it as an open flame) Therefore the hotplate would need to be covered.
If we regard a hotplate as an open flame, then even performing Chazarah should present a concern, as it might still appear that cooking is underway. Conversely, if it does not appear that one is cooking—such as when one is holding the item the entire time—then what is the rationale for requiring Garuf Ukatum for Chazarah at a regular open fire? Additionally, if the hotplate is not considered an open fire and is already katum, why can’t we place items directly on the hotplate during Shabbos?
How can these contradictions be reconciled?

Important nitpick: A plata in English is a warming tray. A "hot plate" is a portable cooking element used by a caterer, it gets a few hundred degrees hot, you put a pot on top of it and actually cook with it. Rabbi Elli Fischer notes this as an example of the need for precision in translation.

100% true, that would seem to go with the difference if it has the power to cook or not. Most poskim I have seen don't make this distinction because at the end of the day, there is a heating element which powers the heat, covered by permanent cover.

Rabbi Willig shlit'a holds that the michzi kebishul concern does not apply to a warming tray, as nobody cooks on them.

@Shalom I've always assumed that's just his not-eating-bacon bias peeking through. Warming trays and griddles even look the same

One way to resolve the contradiction is to assume that returning an item that was previously on the fire (hachzarah) is forbidden (in general) due to a concern of stoking the coals, as opposed to placing an item initially on the fire (hanachah) which is additionally forbidden due to it looking like cooking.
If we consider the plata to be like a kirah ketumah, we have eliminated the concern of stoking the coals, and therefore hachzarah is allowed. But placing cold food directly on the plata could still look like cooking, and therefore a genuine barrier is required between the plata and the cold food, so it no longer looks like cooking.

If i understand your logic you are saying that putting food which is cold on a permanent katum 'fire'  that looks like cooking, doing chazarah does not look like cooking.  Do you have any sources to back this up that there is such a difference?

Why do some hold that can you do chazarah to a kirah ketumah if you haven’t let go of the pot, but not if you have let go of it? One can argue the former looks less like cooking than the latter. In which case kal vechomer taking something from the fridge would be a problem to put on a kirah ketumah.
